# GADInterstitial presentFromRootViewController: causes crash after app resigns from background

Tags: ios, crash

I have a problem after showing an GADInterstitial from admobs.

What I do is:

1. Open an GADInterstitial with presentFromRootViewController:
2. Close it and bring the app in background
3. wait few minutes
4. open the app again
5. click on a UI Element

Now the app crashes with a **SIGSEGV error** with the reason

> objc_msgSend() selector name: _setContentMargin:

. It seams that my memory has some problems and it is new arranged or something. It seams that there is a new object now and it has no responder for the selector. But It only happens after I opened the GADInterstitial once. It runs without problems if I haven´t open the GADInterstitial.

I loaded and show the interstitial like google does in the example... I have no idea what´s going on...

I have a global UIViewController that decides wheather to show ads or not. If not, it wraps the contenViewController directly as ChildViewController. If it has to show Ads, its childviewController will be an "AdViewContoller". This will then wraps the content as ChildViewController:

So I have the following Structure:

- RootViewController -> AdViewController -> ContentViewController

This is my AdViewController:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

let kAD_UNIT_ID_BANNER_AD: String = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
let kAD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_AD: String = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"

let kVIEW_CONTROLLER_ALLOWS_TO_SHOW_INTERSTITIAL_NOTIFICATION: String = "kviewcontrollerallowstoshowinterstitialnotification"

class AdViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {


    var childController: UIViewController? {
        didSet {
            if self.childController != nil {
                self.addChildViewController(self.childController!)
            }
        }
    }
    var contentView: UIView = UIView()
    var adLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    let adView: UIView = UIView();
    let gadAdView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    var intAdView: GADInterstitial?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.childController != nil {
            self.view.addSubview(self.childController!.view)
            self.contentView = self.childController!.view
            self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        self.view.addSubview(self.adView)
        self.adView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.adView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[content]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["content":self.contentView]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[ad]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["ad":self.adView]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[content][ad]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["ad":self.adView, "content":self.contentView]))
        self.adLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.adView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50
        )
        self.adView.addConstraint(self.adLayoutConstraint!)

        self.adView.addSubview(self.gadAdView)
        self.gadAdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.adView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[gad]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["gad":self.gadAdView]))
        self.adView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.gadAdView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.adView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        //self.adView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.gadAdView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 320))

        gadAdView.adUnitID = kAD_UNIT_ID_BANNER_AD
        gadAdView.rootViewController = self
        gadAdView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
        gadAdView.delegate = self

        self.hideBanner()


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "askedForInterstitial:", name: kVIEW_CONTROLLER_ALLOWS_TO_SHOW_INTERSTITIAL_NOTIFICATION, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "initInterstitial", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func hideBanner() -> Void {
        self.adLayoutConstraint?.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    func showBanner() -> Void {
        self.adLayoutConstraint?.constant = 50
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func initInterstitial() -> Void {
        print("UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification called!")
        self.intAdView = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: kAD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_AD)
        let request = GADRequest()
        self.intAdView?.loadRequest(request)
    }


    init(subController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.childController = subController
        self.addChildViewController(self.childController!)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        self.showBanner()
    }
    func adView(bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        self.hideBanner()
    }

    func askedForInterstitial(notification:NSNotification) -> Void {
        if notification.userInfo != nil {
            if let c = notification.userInfo!["controller"] as? UIViewController {
                self.showInterstitialInController(c)
            } else {
                self.showInterstitialInController(self)
            }
        } else {
            self.showInterstitialInController(self)
        }
    }

    class func presentInterstitial() -> Void {
        AdViewController.presentInterstitialInController(nil)
    }

    class func presentInterstitialInController(c: UIViewController?) {
        if c == nil {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kVIEW_CONTROLLER_ALLOWS_TO_SHOW_INTERSTITIAL_NOTIFICATION, object: nil)
        }
        else {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kVIEW_CONTROLLER_ALLOWS_TO_SHOW_INTERSTITIAL_NOTIFICATION, object: nil, userInfo: ["controller": c!])
        }
    }

    private func showInterstitialInController(c: UIViewController) -> Void {
        if self.intAdView != nil && self.intAdView!.isReady {
            self.intAdView!.presentFromRootViewController(c)
        }
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

This Controller has a banner, too. But as I try to show you my whole process, I think you have to see that, too.
I have this two class functions `presentInterstitial` and `presentInterstitialInController` that all childviewcontrollers along the hirarchy can ask to show a interstitial. That works great, but as I said, the problems seam to occure after the app was in the background.

Thank you for your help

Artur

Comment: Add some code. like how you present or dismiss or else.

Comment: Ok... I have the bad line... Because of a reason nobody seams to know: At the end of `viewDidLoad` I add the ViewController as a observer for the Notification `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. If I remove this line, all works perfect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved it...

The problem is not the interstitial, its the line where I add the observer for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification name:

I have a function:

```
func initInterstitial() -> Void {
    print("UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification called!")
    self.intAdView = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: kAD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_AD)
    let request = GADRequest()
    self.intAdView?.loadRequest(request)
}
```

This function I add as an Observer for the

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "initInterstitial", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

No my app crashes after the Notification was called a second time.

Now if I rename the function to `createInterstital`:

```
func createInterstitial() -> Void {
    print("UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification called!")
    self.intAdView = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: kAD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_AD)
    let request = GADRequest()
    self.intAdView?.loadRequest(request)
}
```

and I add the observer like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "createInterstitial", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

All works perfect...

I don´t know why, but the NotificationCenter seems not to like functions with init in it.

Hope this helps some people.

regards

Artur